# WCF request operation timeout

Tags: c#, wcf

I created a WCF service; when I try to consume any methods in the WCF service I am getting the below error:

> "This request operation sent to net.tcp://10.0.0.19:8523/LCAppService/
>   did not receive a reply within the configured timeout
>   (00:00:09.9687490).  The time allotted to this operation may have been
>   a portion of a longer timeout.  This may be because the service is
>   still processing the operation or because the service was unable to
>   send a reply message.  Please consider increasing the operation
>   timeout (by casting the channel/proxy to IContextChannel and setting
>   the OperationTimeout property) and ensure that the service is able to
>   connect to the client."

I have set all the timeout properties (OpenTimeout, CloseTimeout, SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout) with high values.

This error occurs if there is a .NET framework 4.0 on the machine, while if I install the .NET framework 4.5.2 everything works correctly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Timeout exception rarely means time out occured.Most of the cases if framewrok doesnt know what to do ,this error is thrown.Enable fault and check  the logs.

Comment: The IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults property is already enabled.

Comment: What does the log says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and his solution!
To solve the issue I set the MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue in server and client side.
Evidently in the .NET 4.0 framework the default value is set lower than the .NET framework 4.5.2.